# JQuery on home page first visit

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, bpopup

I have successfully added a full screen popup on my homepage using bpopup.

It works great but only works when a button is pressed. I want the popup to appear o the homepage and only the homepage whenever a user visits the site for the first time.

The code i have is:

```
<script>
   // Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
    // Encapsulation
    // $ is assigned to jQuery
    ;(function($) {

         // DOM Ready
        $(function() {

            // Binding a click event
            // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
            $('button').bind('click', function(e) {

                // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                e.preventDefault();

                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                $('#announce').bPopup();

            });

        });

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

This works great but how do i add a cookie related handler to it?

Thanks in advance for any help. Its really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

You will want something like:

```
createCookie("visited", "true", 90);
```

and then just check if that cookie is set using `readCookie()`.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie Plugin  : https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
$.cookie("test", 1);//setting a cookie
$.cookie("test", null);//deleting a cookie
$.cookie("test", 1, { expires : 10 });//setting cookie with time out
```

When you page loads checks the value of cookie as

```
var showDialog=$.cookie("test");
if(showDialog==1)
//showDialog
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Hugely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Cookie pluign](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to add conditions in your code to check if the cookie already exists. Like this

```
if($.cookie('first_visit') != '0'){
    //Show modal as Cookie is not set
    $('#announce').bPopup();
    // now set cookie 
    $.cookie('first_visit', '0'); 
}
```

Comment: How would i make the popup load automatically rather than when a button is pressed?

Comment: Use the code block of $('#announce').bPopup(); inside $(document).ready() instead of inside the click handler function. In that case it will fire just after the dom is ready and wont wait for click. :)

Comment: Sorry, i know this must be annoying but do you mean like this:

Comment: <script src="<?=$this->getThemePath()?>/scripts/jquery.bpopup-0.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

            $(document).ready () {

('#announce').bPopup();

</script>

Comment: <script src="<?=$this->getThemePath()?>/scripts/jquery.bpopup-0.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

            $(document).ready () {

('#announce').bPopup();

</script>

Comment: Check this http://pastie.org/3889077
Do include you pop up script and cookie script before this. It's fine I am also a newbie :)